# Receiving error: "error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range" when constructing class vectors

Tags: c++, class, vector, polymorphism

I am trying to create a script that uses polymorphism to create a set of linking vectors within parent/child class structure. So far I have got the classes setup, but when trying to test the code I receive an error involving static assertion. When analysing the code line by line, I run into the error when I call 'vector.begin() & vector.end()'.

Here is the full script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    vector<vector<A *>> Container;
};

class B : A
{
};

class C : A
{
};

class D : A
{
};

int main()
{
    A ABaseClass;

    B b1, b2;
    C c1, c2;
    D d1, d2;

    vector<B *> b_classes = {&b1, &b2};
    vector<C *> c_classes = {&c1, &c2};
    vector<D *> d_classes = {&d1, &d2};

    ABaseClass.Container = {
        {b_classes.begin(), b_classes.end()},
        {c_classes.begin(), c_classes.end()},
        {d_classes.begin(), d_classes.end()}};
}
```

Compiling gives this error:

```
error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
  138 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
      |                                                                        ^~~~~

error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
```

I have narrowed down the cause of the error to this section:

```
ABaseClass.Container = {
        {b_classes.begin(), b_classes.end()},
        {c_classes.begin(), c_classes.end()},
        {d_classes.begin(), d_classes.end()}};
```

Following the root of the problem leads me to the file 'stl_uninitialized.h', and the line:

```
[138]      static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
                                                                            ^~~~~
```

I have been trying to get the child classes to be tracked by the parents but I am unfamiliar with vectors and pointers so I am a bit stuck. Any help with moving forward would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a nit-pick, but C++ programs are called *programs*, not "scripts".

Comment: You have the private inheritances, thus no one of B* - D* can be cast to A*.

Comment: Changing `class` to `struct` not only fixes the issue, you get to learn that `struct` and `class` in C++ mean the same thing, with the only difference being the default access specifier when inheriting and for member variables.

Comment: I will be sure to refer to them as programs in the future. Thank you for the responses I will try a couple of things to see what works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upcast to a base class is ill-formed if the inheritance is not public. i.e

```
struct base {};
class derived : base {}; // private inheritance

int main(){
    derived a;
    auto & b = static_cast<base &>(a); // invalid
}
```

That's exactly what that last assignment expression is trying to do. You will need to inherit publically. i.e

```
class A

public:
vector<vector<A *>> Container;
};

class B : public A
{
};

class C : public A
{
};

class D : public A
{
};
```

EDIT:
This is the answer originally cited:

```
class A

public:
vector<vector<A *>> Container;
};

struct B : A
{
};

struct C : A
{
};

struct D : A
{
};
```

Comment: You should add the version that uses `class B`, `class C`, etc. so that the OP sees that there is no difference between `struct` and `class`, except for the default access specifier.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, thank you. Using structs instead of classes worked.

Comment: @Staz -- You should have added the `class` version, not remove the `struct` version.